# alternative way to store JS vars and canvas data that user can retrieve later?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cookies

I have a canvas element that the user draws many objects onto. Currently, the object positioning information is stored in JS variables:

```
object1Xposition = 235;
object1Yposition = 30;

object1Xscale = 100;
object1Yscale = 110;

object1rotation = 22.5;
```

...and so forth. At some point the user clicks a button to save all the positioning info to a cookie:

```
createCookie('CCobj1Xpos',object1Xposition,.01);
createCookie('CCobj1Ypos',object1Yposition,.01);
createCookie('CCobj1Xscale',object1Xscale,.01);
```

Later, the user returns to the page to load the cookie back in:

```
var a = readCookie('CCobj1Xpos');
var b = readCookie('CCobj1Ypos');
var c = readCookie('CCobj1Xscale');
```

I also have it set up where the canvas.toDataURL is also saved to the cookie.
All of this works ok, but I'm concerned about the file size, because there may be too many object info to fit in a cookie. I understand 4K is susually the standard.
Is there an alternative way, using only HTML and Javascript, for the user to store simple variable info AND canvas data info, that can be retrieved and redrawn later? By the way, the canvas todataurl info is only used in this way so it can be passed to my email via formmail script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try local storage.  It's exactly what you need, and it's documented [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).  The trick is that if you want to support old browsers, you need to fall back to cookies.  Also, localstorage values are stored as strings, and need to be converted back into your data type.

Example of storing data:

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    localStorage.CCobj1Xpos = object1Xposition;
} else {
    createCookie('CCobj1Xpos',object1Xposition,.01);
}
```

And retrieving data:

```
var a = null;
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    a = Number(localStorage.CCobj1Xpos);
} else {
    a = readCookie('CCobj1Xpos');
}
```

Comment: localStorage was implemented in most browsers before canvas element so fallback should not be needed.